# javax.naming.NamingException: Could not create resource factory instance

Tags: jsp, tomcat

First of all i'm not a Java developer. I just need to get a simple jsp examples that connects to a postgres database and retrieve some information.

**I got it running on a local env**, but when i try to run on production server ( Apache Tomcat 6.0.29 ), it just doesn't work. Page displays the following exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc/postgres"
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:491)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:401)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

I noticed that when i reload the application, catalina.out shows the following problem:

```
Aug 23, 2011 2:21:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener addResource
WARNING: Failed to register in JMX: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not create resource factory instance [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory]
```

At WEB-INF/lib i have the following files:

```
# ls -lh
total 1.3M
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tomcat tomcat  17K Aug 23 14:15 jstl.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tomcat tomcat 160K Mar  5  2007 naming-factory-dbcp.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tomcat tomcat 528K Aug 23 14:18 postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tomcat tomcat 313K Aug 23 14:16 standard.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tomcat tomcat 248K Aug 22 22:18 tomcat-dbcp.jar
```

I tried googling about this but all solutions mention naming-factory-dbcp.jar that is already there. Any ideas of what i should do?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is my tomcat lib:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat nobody  11K Jun  8  2009 lib/annotations-api.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat nobody  49K Jun  8  2009 lib/catalina-ant.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat nobody 121K Jun  8  2009 lib/catalina-ha.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat nobody 1.1M Jun  8  2009 lib/catalina.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat nobody 225K Jun  8  2009 lib/catalina-tribes.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat nobody  28K Jun  8  2009 lib/el-api.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat nobody 101K Jun  8  2009 lib/jasper-el.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat nobody 501K Jun  8  2009 lib/jasper.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat nobody 1.4M Jun  8  2009 lib/jasper-jdt.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat nobody  75K Jun  8  2009 lib/jsp-api.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat nobody  86K Jun  8  2009 lib/servlet-api.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat nobody 732K Jun  8  2009 lib/tomcat-coyote.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat nobody 193K Jun  8  2009 lib/tomcat-dbcp.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat nobody  65K Jun  8  2009 lib/tomcat-i18n-es.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat nobody  43K Jun  8  2009 lib/tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat nobody  48K Jun  8  2009 lib/tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
```

Comment: You might not be initializing the jdbc/postgres driver in a correct way. Kindly check for the syntax and check if the required libraries are loaded in the project classpath. The correct way to do is `jdbc:postgresql://server_name`

Comment: Fine that you included the listing of `Tomcat/lib`. But key point as answered by home is that you should **never** include server-specific libraries in webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`. It makes the webapp unportable to servers of different make/version. It'll result in classpath troubles. Did you remove them from `/WEB-INF/lib`? The `Tomcat/lib` folder should be kept untouched. At highest, you drop the JDBC driver in there, but do definitely not change or remove Tomcat's own libraries.

Comment: @Rakesh Hi, it looks correct. The same app works on my local host, but not on production server.

Comment: @BalucC Yep, just removed naming-factory-dbcp.jar and tomcat-dbcp.jar from my application lib. But i still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

`dbcp` classes should already be available in `tomcat/lib`. There is no need to include then in your WAR file - it may lead to class loader irritations if you use the wrong version. Try to remove the `...dbcp.jar` files from your WEB-INF/lib directory, put the `postgres...jar` to `tomcat/lib` and restart Tomcat.

Comment: I tried to remove dbcp.jar files from it but it's didn't worked, same error. I edited my question to show my tomcat's lib folder content.

Comment: So your code works in the local environment but not on the server, right?

Comment: Right. The difference is that at local env i'm running version 6.0.33.

Comment: Ok, maybe you modified some other files in your local env and did not remember to update those on the server, e.g. `context.xml`? Check the manual again, maybe you missed something: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html